# Is it possible to obtain a trace output from the Microchip Debugger?

Tags: breakpoints, trace, microchip

Testing an assembly program in Microchip Studio (V. 7.0.2594) shows a strange behaviour which probably is caused by a bug in the EEPROM simulation. Running through my program with the debugger without any single-stepping ends up by halting "somewhere out in the green" while stepping through it is endless since the simulator probably is waiting for the EEPROM write process to finish.
Therefore my question is: Is there any possibility to get a log file from the simulator about what it is doing?
I wouldn't mind getting some thousands of repeated lines but I would eagerly look for the couple of lines just after the repeated ones!
In the manual of Microchip Studio I wasn't able to find such a feature...

Comment: If you work with MPLABX you could try this: Select File>Project Properties, “Simulator” category, “Trace” option category. 2. Change “Data Collection Selection” from “Off” to “Instruction Trace”. This is the type of trace used by the simulator

Comment: Unfortunately MPLABX doesn't support Atmel types of processors...

Comment: Which controller are you missing? The newest version 6.20 contains a lot Atmel chips.

Comment: Here is a list with supported devices: https://packs.download.microchip.com/DeviceDoc/Device_Support.pdf

Comment: I'm working with ATMEGA328P, and - yes - I have seen that processor in the list.  Many thanks for the hint - I will come back to it if my investigations will not come to a result. However, doing a lot of testing and - awesome!!! - single stepping through my program I have found a probable reason - or rather constellation - where the error seems to happen - so I prefer to continue at that trace...